# How to add a Sum, Avarage to Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column, view

I must add an Avarage field to Calculated Column. How could I add an Avarage sum to Calculated column. When I tried to add by the View, the View doesn't see calculated Column.

Comment: Are you trying to add calculated column to the view via SharePoint UI? Can you include a screenshot of view settings?

Comment: Yes I'm traing to add a Sum or Median to the View, and its show only when i add another test column.

Comment: It's not possible "out of the box", if you can use a workflow on change/create you can set a single line of text field to the value you use in the calculated instead. If that's not an option, we will need some more info, like Version of SharePoint you are using and technologies you can use (eg javascript only, server side etc)

Comment: I use Sharepoint 2013 and try use default View, but Sharepoint dont see Calculated column on View